# Way to "de-prioritize" down voted posts to improve first experience

Tags: feature-request

I'm not in anyway an expert on how StackExchange technology works, so forgive me. What I do know is that first impressions count for a lot and sometimes our entire first "page" of newest questions are all topics that will probably get deleted or spammed.

I know newest literally means newest. I also know most people click newest before anything else and doesn't the site default to that?

Just hoping to improve experience.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Joel. It is a good observation. Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: It's a tough question. Newest should be newest. So I guess the question is should the default view be "Newest" or a filtered view that moves down voted (or maybe just being voted for close) appears lower.